# Swift tableview data population

Tags: uitableview, swift

Making just a simple Tableview in swift, The tableview doesn't populate anything at all. THe image is being populated.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier";
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell;

    if !(cell != nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
            reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    }

    if(indexPath.row==0){
        cell!.textLabel.text = "POG Validation"
        cell!.imageView.image =  UIImage(named: "myImg")
    }

return cell;
```

The frame of `cell!.textLabel` is (0,0,0,0). And no data is being populated.

```
(lldb) po cell!.textLabel;

<UITableViewLabel: 0x7ce6c510; frame = (0 0; 0 0); userInteractionEnabled =  NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ce6c5d0>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I fixed your compile errors, your code worked fine:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier";
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell;

    if !(cell != nil){
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
            reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    }

    if(indexPath.row==0){
        // your forgot the '?'s
        cell!.textLabel?.text = "POG Validation"
        cell!.imageView?.image =  UIImage(named: "myImg")
    }

    return cell!; // you forgot the '!'
}
```

I would have written it like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "cellIdentifier";
    let dequedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
    let cell = dequedCell ?? UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    if(indexPath.row==0){
        cell.textLabel?.text = "POG Validation"
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "myImg")
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it about same way as yours. sorry for accepting this late. :-)